# extract tag info from html text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

i am trying to scrape the webpage.i got the below text. How to extract the src info from the below string. can anyone tell  me the process how can we extract any key value data from the text

```
<img id="imgsglx2" onerror="this.alt=not select the picture or pictures cannot be displayed" src="http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg" style=" border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;height:110px;width:110px; "/>
```

and text inside the textarea tag.

```
  <textarea id="sgmsbck" name="sgms" style="width:98%;height:120px">On August. 19, 2014\uff0c08:30, Mr. Xiao who drove lu K9**** MPV from south to north along the TaiShang south Road, when Mr. Xiao drove lu K9**** MPV turn west at the crossing of Chengshan road and TaiShang south road, RongCheng City. Due to wrong behavior towards pedestrians at pedestrian crossings, the left part of the lu K9**** MPV impacted with Mr. Song(Pedestrian) from south to north across ChengShan Road of the pedestrian crossings. Causing the lu K9**** MPV damaged, Mr. Song injured.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned `beautifulsoup` in tags, I assume you want to use it to parse your html content.

```
import bs4

content = """<img id="imgsglx2" onerror="this.alt=not select the picture or pictures cannot be displayed" src="http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg" style=" border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;height:110px;width:110px; "/>
<textarea id="sgmsbck" name="sgms" style="width:98%;height:120px">On August. 19, 2014\uff0c08:30, Mr. Xiao who drove lu K9**** MPV from south to north along the TaiShang south Road, when Mr. Xiao drove lu K9**** MPV turn west at the crossing of Chengshan road and TaiShang south road, RongCheng City. Due to wrong behavior towards pedestrians at pedestrian crossings, the left part of the lu K9**** MPV impacted with Mr. Song(Pedestrian) from south to north across ChengShan Road of the pedestrian crossings. Causing the lu K9**** MPV damaged, Mr. Song injured.</textarea>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

img = soup.find('img') # locate img tag
text_area = soup.find('textarea') # locate textarea tag

print img['id'] # print value of 'id' attribute in img tag
print img['src'] # print value of 'src' attribute
print text_area.text # print content in this tag
```

Answer (score 0):

[beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) can help:

A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag  has an attribute “class” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:

```
tag['class']

# u'boldest'
```

You can access that dictionary directly as .attrs:

```
tag.attrs
# {u'class': u'boldest'}
```

and you can get text out of tag by .text

```
tag.text
```